# Syncing immutable folders on linux (rsync/unison/some thing else?)

Tags: linux, sync, rsync, nfs

Consider the following directory layout:

```
/foo
  /ABZE1
     a1.txt
     a2.txt
     ...
     a59682.txt
  /BBSDF
     b1.txt
     b2.txt
     ....
     b42333.txt
  ...
```

`foo` is the parent folder, each of it's subdirectories (`ABZE1`,`BBSDF`,...) is in fact **immutable** in that it has a unique name which implies it's version. This means that once such a sub-directory is created it is **never** modified. Also, each of these sub-directories have **a lot** of files (sometimes > 100K).

I need to do a 2-way sync of `foo` with `foo-remote` (an NFS mount on the same machine).

`rsync` will do the job, but it has poor performance since it checks the size/timestamp of *all* the files. If I could get `rsync` to check **only the folders** that would work. Same for `unison`.

Can we tell `rsync` to treat the folder as the entity to compare (and not the files inside the sub-folder)? Is there any other tool that can achieve this synchronization?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is _immutable_... Is the server accessible over SSH? For both rsync and unison, that would be the best option.

Comment: Thanks @grawity, *immutable* indeed... Server is accessible over SSH, the problem is not in the protocol as much as it is in the synchronizing application behaviour.

Comment: The problem _is_ partially in the protocol. With NFS, both rsync and unison think they're working locally; over SSH, they can use a much more efficient protocol – both for comparing files and for transferring changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, what you are asking of `rsync` is not possible. However, the following command

```
diff <(ls) <(ssh me@remote "cd /path/to/remote/backup/directory && ls")
```

lists in a single swoop the differences between the two directory structures, identifying the differences between them. Pls notice that this works if you have setup authentication by crypto keys on the remote server, otherwise you will be asked for a password, possibly messing up the whole thing.

If you want, you can make this skip files (hence work faster, presumably), by modifying it to:

```
diff <(find . -type d)  <(ssh me@remote "cd /path/to/remote/backup/directory && find . -type d")
```

The command above only queries directories.

You can now parse it by means of:

```
 ...(command above)... | grep "<" | awk '{print $2}'
```

which will spit out just the names of the directories that exist on the first pc but not on the second one (because I used `grep "<"` instead of `grep ">"`).

It should be trivial now to `rsync` only the directories discovered this way.

Comment: Cool. This looks exactly like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Stav Just one thing : I forgot to stress that, for this to work, you must have setup authentication by crypto keys on the remote site.

Comment: Yep figured that from the fact I need a password-less SSH session. I'll also try running the diff between the local directory and the NFL share as it might be simpler